# Python 2.7: How to split a CSV file properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to split a string I get after extracting text from an URL. The extracted data is put in a CSV file, and I am trying to separate the the data.

```
playerInfo = items[i].getText(separator=u'%|-').encode('utf-8').split('%|-')
```

What I am trying to achieve is to remove the `%` and `-`. An example of data I extract:

```
<div style="padding-left:20px; width:280px; float:left">&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="default.asp?id=19&amp;spillerid=739&amp;todo=arkiv">Alexander Back - Forsvar</a><br></div>
```

So what I want from this is to separate the name `Alexander Back` and the position `Forsvar`, and remove `-`

In my CSV I have two columns; one for the name and one for position. I extract the data by doing:

```
items = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'style': 'padding-left:20px; width:280px; float:left'})
```

This is how I imagine the output in the CSV file to be:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.get_text(strip=True)` to help with getting the text. Then a further bit of stripping and splitting would give you the two values:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

html = """
<div style="padding-left:20px; width:280px; float:left">&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="default.asp?id=19&amp;spillerid=739&amp;todo=arkiv">Alexander Back1 - Forsvar1</a><br></div>
<div style="padding-left:20px; width:280px; float:left">&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="default.asp?id=19&amp;spillerid=739&amp;todo=arkiv">Alexander Back2 - Forsvar2</a><br></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Name', 'Position'])

    for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'style': 'padding-left:20px; width:280px; float:left'}):
        csv_output.writerow([e.strip() for e in div.get_text(strip=True).strip('-').split('-')])
```

Giving you an `output.csv` file looking like:

```
Name,Position
Alexander Back1,Forsvar1
Alexander Back2,Forsvar2
```